# Devise with additional user fields, nested models / attributes and custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have posted a few related questions on this but now I am at a road block. I had this system working quite well and then I went to add to it and now I broke it real good!

First off I just discovered Gist so here is my code:

https://gist.github.com/jasper502/065a63fde266fac1fbf5

The idea here is that I have a single User login that can eventually be tied to multiple Companies via the Role.

You signup via Devise on the custom /register route and fill out the Company information etc. The custom registration controller creates the Role during the user creation and sets a few other attributes.

When I try to create a new user / company the additional user fields (name_first & name_last) always fail validation regardless if they are in fact valid. The nested Company fields do not validate at all. If I enter the email and password field only the form works but only creates the User record.

To me it seems like the custom registration controller is not being processed at all because it seems to not want to allow my additional params specified in sign_up_params.

On a trial and error basis I tried this:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions], :controllers => { :registrations => 'users/registrations', :sessions => 'users/sessions' }
   as :user do
     get '/signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
     post '/signin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
     delete '/signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

I wanted to see if the normal Devise routes work and they do except that now the validation seems to be bypassed completely. If I submit a blank form I get all kinds of errors but if I fill it out it works fine now. I am getting close but obviously missing something small here.

So to clarify:

- if I create custom registration routes the additional fields always fail validation (even with correct data) and the nested objects are not created
- if I use the stock Devise routes the form works great IF you enter in the data correct because the validations break and permit any values
- again I did have this working but am not in a position to easily role this back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched my routes to "user/..." from "devise/..." and that seemed to do the trick.

Hope this helps someone else.